# how to style react native expo picker in android

Tags: react-native

how to style react native expo picker in android , like changing the font Size and centering text and changing the background of the text input

```
 <Picker
            selectedValue={branch}
            mode="dropdown"
            style={{
                // fontSize: 24, 
                // borderRadius: 14,
                backgroundColor: '#BEDCEF',
                height: 40,
                // alignItems: 'center',
                // justifyContent:'center',
                // alignContent:'center',
                // shadowColor:'black',
                // shadowOffset:{width:0,height:2},
                // shadowRadius:6,
                // shadowOpacity:0.26,
                width:350,
               elevation:10,
                // marginBottom:290
                
                
            }}
            itemStyle ={{
                fontSize: 24, 
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent:'center',
                color:'red',
                backgroundColor:'purple'

            }}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setBranch(itemValue)}

        >
```

Comment: Is not supported https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-picker/issues/47

Answer (score 0):

the only option you have atm is to change the color of the drop down icon using the prop (supported in latest version)

```
  dropdownIconColor={}
```